# What can I do about a user consistently spreading misinformation?

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-user

Consider these (excerpts from) comments:

1. > The windows methods are more efficient than FileStream in opening and copying files. Window copy does not open the file.

   Wrong: `CopyFile` *does* open the file and read it in chunks, writing the chunks to the destination file. Also, I'd love to see a benchmark for said claim. Sure, managed code adds some overhead, but once JITted and all it comes down to the same Windows API calls.

   Irrelevant to the post: the question was about how to remove bytes from the beginning of a file.
2. > Any DLL that is used in you app have to be in the same folder as the exe file for your project

   Wrong: DLLs are searched for in a variety of locations and alternative locations can be given.

   Irrelevant to the post: the DLL *was* already in the bin directory as stated in the question, it was a web application (no executable), it was probably about dependencies or version mismatches as usual when .NET claims it can't find a DLL.
3. > An Http message cannot have binary data. You must use Convert to Base64 string. I would use FTP which has a binary mode. FTP is a sub class of HTTP which is meant to transfer files. FTP in binary mode automatically does the conversion to Base64 string.

   Wrong: I don't even know where to begin. Not a single sentence holds any value.
4. > DO NOT USE THE MDF FILE NAME IN THEN CONNECTION STRING!!! The database is already connected to the server and the server owns the file so you cannot connect.

   Wrong: with LocalDB, you can use a filename in your connection string. The second sentence makes no sense whatsoever.
5. > A connection has three properties 1) Source IP address 2) Destination IP address 3) Port number. You can only have one connection where all three properties are the same. You are trying to open a second connection with the same parameters.

   Wrong: source and destination port both count as a separate component of sockets. Otherwise you can't make two connections from one machine to the other at the same destination port. Your browser does this to download resources in parallel.

These comments have the following in common:

- They're posted by the same user
- They're at most partially correct, or more common, grossly incorrect
- They're not incidents, but a pattern, the five above were posted in a two hour timespan
- The user keeps posting comments like this and ignores attempts of other users to correct them, or doubles down and starts trolling

I think these comments are harmful for the site, because they at least confuse the OP of the question or answer they are posted under, and they spread misinformation. This pattern has been going on for years, there's true comedy gold in their profile, but I don't think it's OK to have on the site.

I'm not certain they're doing this on purpose. Maybe they think they're correct, maybe they think they're helping. Knowing that I cannot change this person, but I desperately want them to stop spreading confusion, what can I do?

- Ignore it (not improving the site)
- Keep replying to them, hopefully at least educating the OP they're leaving these comments for (not very productive)
- Flag it with a custom mod message, mention that they're wrong, hope the mod follows up (not very productive)
- ...?

**Edit 2020-01-15**: it's happened again (multiple times since asking this question actually). A comment was posted to a non-repro question without relevant exception information:

> What version of Net are you using (platform). The system library have namespace reserved for linq, but the linq is in a separate dll. So you the compiler will no give errors but you will get an exception when running. So for some reason the ling library is not installed or not part of the Net Library installed.

This is, again, nonsense in every way imaginable. I responded along the lines of:

> @user, can you please stop doing this? This error is not being caused by LINQ being partially installed, you're confusing the OP and other readers deliberately.

It may or may not have contained harsher words like "nonsense" or "misinformation". Last time I checked, my comment had three upvotes.

A moderator came along, and deleted my comment, but theirs remains. I'm done.

Comment: In regards to *"Flag it with a custom mod message"* I doubt the mods will appreciate that; the mods aren't there to determine the "correctness" of an answer/comment, only that it meets the terms of the SE community. The best thing to do, in my opinion, is keep informing them of why their comment is wrong. If it's an answer, downvote. If you do keep informing them, hopefully they're learn something.

Comment: @Larnu exactly. But I don't have enough time to correct all the nonsense they post; most of it goes unnoticed.

Comment: Unfortunately, as many of us are aware, a lot of bad answers also go unnoticed, or noticed but remain with upvotes; especially if the first answer is bad during a quiet period and it's accepted before anyone else looks at it. I wouldn't suggest that you seek out the user's comments, and correct them all, but if you see a comment from them on a question you're viewing that you disagree with/know is wrong then comment. It isn't anyone's job to "police" the site. If your comment is correct, and theirs is wrong, hopefully yours will get upvotes, and the other (wrong) comment will be deleted.

Comment: Downvote them. In case if it is still incorrectly upvoted, bring it to meta.

Comment: You can't downvote a comment @Ḿűỻịgǻṇącểơửṩᛗ .

Comment: Then the comments that follow the incorrect comment might be used to prove a diamond intervention flag.

Comment: There are no links or names in this post, still it takes no more than 3-4 clicks to get the missing information. I think it would be fair to ping them about this this meta Q.

Comment: @Brak fair enough, I've done that.

Comment: You've gotta cool it with the tone and accusations. Correcting misinformation is fine, but your comment was so borderline that I can see why the moderator who reviewed it felt that it was over the line. I've deleted the original comment now, too, since it barely made any sense anyway. But please understand that when you hurl accusations like you did ("stop it with the nonsense" and "stop deliberately confusing other users for your own pleasure"), you yourself become part of the problem.

Comment: @Cody agreed, and sorry about that. I should not let my frustration with this situation get the better of me.

Comment: How I wish I could bounty this, or upvote it 100 times. This user posts some of the most weirdly and egregiously wrong comments I've *ever* seen. If I didn't know better, I'd think they were a poorly written AI. I'd guess that 50% of the comments are just plain wrong, and often dangerously so. How they got to 30k rep is a mystery to me. I guess it's a 'stopped clock' kinda thing.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you can have a discussion with them, show them evidence why they are wrong and they then just leave without deleting their comments. Having these things left on the site is detrimental to Stack Overflow and the unfortunate users that come across them

Comment: There's a user who post comments in the somewhat obscure tags that I have expertise in who sounds exactly like the user you (and @DavidG) are describing. At times I have *begged* him to stop posting comments, but he keeps going because he really means well and thinks he's an expert. I wonder if it's the same user? In my user's case, he often gets responses in and in the ensuing comment discussion the OP eventually realizes he doesn't really understand and just stops interacting.

Comment: @President one of their most recent comments was: _"Certificates never get transferred between client and server. Only the name of the certificates get transferred. The certificates must be loaded before the request is sent on both client and server. TLS the server sends a certificate block with list of names of possible certificates. The client then looks up names in stores to find matching name. Client code can choose any of the names or a particular name"_ which is ... not quite how it works, nor the slightest bit of helpful.

Comment: Ok, definitely the same guy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do anything to those comments. You can do something in response, like this meta post, or posting contradictory / corrective comments.

However, with regards to the comments themselves, there is nothing you can do.

Maybe if we had downvotes for comments people would stop posting such content.

For instance, consider that 1 out of 5 people are misinformed with regards to the issues you raise. Further, that all 5 try to vote, and that there were 100 people. There are now 20 upvotes on that comment. It looks legitimate. Future users suffer from misinformation. Now imagine seeing that comment at -60... Which way was more desirable?

Comment: You forgot the *ideal* approach, which is to write a good answer that solves the problem and addresses misinformation in the comments. That way, it’s preserved and visible for everyone.

Comment: @CodyGray - That get's into responding, as I note here. In a super rare *ideal* situation, it *may* work. However, it most likely doesn't work in the vast majority of situations. What we are left with as a result is this massive space where users are in a grey zone, hence this exact question. When users lack the tooling to properly address content, they use improper tools. What they really need, is an actual path towards addressing this right at the source. That is the *ideal* solution.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. A way to jump into another user’s brain and stop them from having wrong ideas. Yes, indeed, we need this urgently.

Comment: @CodyGray - Not sure how you got to that assumption. We need to downvote comments, now more than ever. That is the tool users lack, and instead of having the ability to downvote a comment, they take alternative action.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on the comments I made:

The nature of comments is quite different to that of answers (and questions). A very easy way to react to an answer that is wrong (even if only partially) is to downvote it. If you want, you can comment on the answer too, and advise why but many of us are too aware of the problem of revenge votes (and the immaturity of them).

If it is an answer, and the other is (partially) wrong, you would be better off downvoting and then posting your own (in fact I personally suggest you *do* post your own answer). Possibly reference the other answer and advise in there as the problems it has, while improving on it. That gives a lot more people the chance to learn that way.

Comments, on the other hand, can't be downvoted; only upvoted. This means you can't vote down a comment because it's wrong. The only thing you can do as a visual response is respond with an additional comment underneath, pinging the user who made the incorrect statement. *Hopefully* they will read said comment and delete it. If not, one can hope that at least your comment gets voted up so that future readers of the comments know yours is useful.

Custom Mod Flaps for these seem like a bad idea; as I mentioned the mods aren't here to determine if an answer/comment is correct. Many of the mods are specialised in a specific language or three like the rest of us so flagging a comment on a python question may be reviewed by some mods that are C# or Rust experts. They can't determine whether the comment is wrong if they don't know the language, nor are they expected to.

I also think that ignoring them is the wrong choice too, like you inferred. Having wrong answers, even in the comments, doesn't improve the site. Responding tio the comment therefore seems like the most correct thing to do, as it tries to educate both the user that commented and the future readers.

As mentioned above by @HansPassant , you could flag the comment as no longer needed. I don't think these will always be relevant, and i suspect that constantly flagging a specific users comments as "no longer needed" is going to go down well either. Perhaps if the other user responds to you, but doesn't delete, you could ensure you always do it, or in circumstances where your comment disputing it has multiple upvotes; as it has the "backing" of the community. Simply flagging it immediately, even if you do response, is effectively the same as asking the mod to determine "right and wrong" information, which isn't what we should be asking of them.

---

TL;DR: Respond and give a description of why the comment is wrong. If the OP responds and doesn't delete their comment, flag it as no longer needed. If your comment also gets some upvotes (and theirs doesn't), you could flag their comment too; as it makes it *appear* your comment has the "backing" of the community and is correct.

In regards to the point below:

> The user keeps posting comments like this and ignores attempts of other users to correct them, or doubles down and starts trolling

If they are trolling, raise an "Unfriendly or unkind" flag; that type of behaviour isn't welcome on any of the SE communities.

Comment: Mods are exception handlers, and IMO this is enough of an exception to warrant a mod flag. You're not supposed to flag _single_ incorrect comments, a pattern of multiple blatantly wrong comments is worth a mod flag imo, and they're blatantly wrong enough for any mod to spot. I never bulk (>3) flag a single user across multiple posts, that's always a mod flag.

Comment: It’s a reasonable case for a mod flag *conceptually*, @Erik, but what do you want a moderator to do? You want us to go read their comments, do research to assess their veracity, and then either delete the comments or decline the flag? Should we also message the user and politely request that they stop being wrong? Maybe link them to some tutorials and/or reference guides that we found useful in our own research of their comments’ veracity?

Comment: @CodyGray If it's not very obvious, I'd expect a mod to decline, but in this case I suspect trolling, so I'd hope on a mod message with _this stuff doesn't belong in comments, and no back and forth about facts without providing a reference_ giving him the benefit of doubt, and if he continues, likely suspension (and since all mods are programmers I'd be surprised if there's a mod that couldn't confidently dispute at least 2 of these comments without doing any research).

Comment: The comments excerpted in the question here absolutely do not look like trolling to me, @Erik. I can quibble with a couple of them, indeed; namely the first, second, and third. But I say “quibble” very deliberately, because these comments are not altogether wrong. The Windows copy functions *are* going to be more efficient than rolling your own with FileStream. DLLs *do* have to be in the app folder, unless special measures are taken otherwise. HTTP responses are meant to contain text. They can indeed contain binary data, but only because computers don’t actually distinguish text from binary.

Comment: The actual trolling I'm talking about follows after discussing with said user. The first comment in the question eventually elicited a now-removed comment that read something like _"Microsoft doesn't hire Software Science people [...] I wish people used a real OS like Unix"_.

Comment: And a comment like that would be flaggable, @CodeCaster. But not really what we’re talking about here, as I understand it, which is advice that is almost correct, but not quite, and thus may be misleading.

Comment: @Cody yeah that's a clear case, the rest not so much. I've also expanded the question to explain what I think is wrong with those comments.

Answer (score 5):

This is the problem with giving answers/advice in the comments: **you can't downvote comments.**

[Comments are for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> - Request[ing] **clarification** from the author;
> - Leav[ing] **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;

None of these comments do either, so they're serving no purpose. As such, **flag as No Longer Needed** and move on. If the user wants their technical advice to be heeded, they can move the information into an answer and let it be judged like other answers. In which case you can downvote the misleading/incorrect content.

Comment: No. Please do not flag comments as “no longer needed” because they contain incorrect information. This is a misuse of the flag.

Comment: @Cody I'm not advocating flagging comments NLN for incorrect information. I'm advocating flagging comments NLN for misusing the purpose of comments. I'd do the same for any comment-answer I saw.

Comment: It’s still an incorrect use of the flag. It isn’t the comment equivalent of a downvote. We do not delete comments that appear to convey useful information, and there’s no reliable way for a moderator to make the determination that these comments do not convey useful information because they happen to be wrong. That’s a slippery slope anyway; we don’t delete comments because they are incorrect. That you think they should be answers is irrelevant.

Comment: Perhaps I overspoke, @CodeCaster. Replace “we” with “I”, and the statement becomes correct.

Comment: @Cody again, the fact that the comment is "useful" or "correct" plays no part in my reasoning to flag. See the privilege link I posted. These comments fall under "When *shouldn't* I comment?" since it's a "Secondary discussion." *That's* why I'm saying flag NLN.

Comment: It seems I’m still not being clear. Let me try again. That you personally think something should have been posted as an answer, not a comment, is ***not*** grounds to flag that comment as “no longer needed”.

Comment: @Cody sorry for the not-so-constructive prior comment, but over the past months or more I've seen comments disappear left and right, whether they contain useful information or not. It appears to me that _any_ comment flagged as "No Longer Needed" disappears eventually. So I'd advocate that the advice from this answer works. I just don't like people who are wasting time by handing out red herrings (or whatever the idiom is), and I want it to stop if I can help it. So if not with NLN-flags, how _can_ I?

Comment: I’m cautioning against this answer, because if I personally start seeing an account abuse NLN flags on comments as described here, I may take action against the flagger. You asked the question, @Code; I upvoted it. Just because I’m telling you that an option proposed by an answer is the wrong option doesn’t obligate me to give you a different option. It’s a hard problem, I agree. Off the top of my head, your options are to ignore it, or to leave a comment reply addressing the nuances. Perhaps the *best* option is to post an answer that also addresses incorrect or misleading advice in comments

Comment: @Cody alright, thanks for explaining that, it clears the air for me!

Comment: Ahh I see, @Cody. If that's the case, then how should a "When shouldn't I comment" comment be flagged?

Comment: Read the description of the “no longer needed” flag. Or just the name. Is the comment obsolete? Has its purpose been served? If so, a NLN flag is appropriate. Don’t overthink it or contort it. None of this, “oh, it’s no longer needed because it’s bad advice, and nobody needs bad advice”. The “When shouldn’t I comment” advice in the comments privilege page is merely that: advice. They’re advisory guidelines. It doesn’t necessarily mean that a comment should be flagged. I really hate destroying value, so I’m not going to delete a comment because it could/should have been posted as an answer.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, @Cody, and see where you're coming from. But what you're saying is directly contradictory to what I've heard and seen both here on SO and around the network. Could you point me to some meta discussions that backup this stance?

Comment: Other sites have been essentially forced to adopt draconian policies to stem the flood of comments due to the nature of their topics, like Politics, Workplace, and Interpersonal Skills. I have my concerns about this approach, but I understand the motivation. Stack Overfow doesn’t do this because we don’t have a real problem with this. Our motto has always been that we avoid destroying value, meaning we don’t throw the baby out with the bathwater. There are plenty of Meta discussions about that philosophy. Reading anything posted by me or Robert Harvey will get you started.