# Users posting answers as comments because they cannot be downvoted. This makes me sad

Tags: discussion, comments

I just had an interaction with a user who posted a very terse comment as an attempted answer.  Admittedly, I went a little too far in my sarcastic/silly response, but it turns out he is not a native English speaker and the reason he said he posted a comment is because he "doesn't need the points" and "When you post answers, people give downvotes for no good reason".

I paraphrased in hopes nobody tries to identify him.  But I felt bad.  Is this a systemic problem or is he a bad answerer?  He has fairly high rep.  A deeper look into his profile shows he has over 3k answers, as recently as an hour ago.  So is he just lying?  Perhaps answers he's not really confident on he posts as comments so they cannot be downvoted?  In this case, it was an extremely low-effort answer.

Can anything be done about this? Is there anything to do?

> [image]

Comment: p.s. I'm sure I'll get downvoted for this. That's okay, "I don't need the points" :)
p.p.s. I didn't know I could create tags. I thought "not-a-comment" would be funny since there is a "not-an-answer" tag.  Oops.

Comment: I write comments containing the core of an answer when I don't have the time (or energy) to provide a good answer.  I don't do that because I care about down-votes; I do that because what I can provide in a comment isn't sufficient to count as a 'good answer' in my eyes.  My intention is that the comment should help the OP, but it isn't up to the standard I require in an answer that has my name against it.

Comment: If you don't want the tag to stay, remove it from your question and it will disappear eventually, as long as no one else uses it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments)

Comment: FWIW I 100% agree with this. People don't need to provide answers as comments. Unfortunately some mods disagree, and even more problematic is that mods can only convert answers to comments, not the other way around, IIRC.

Comment: I'm squarely in @JonathanLeffler's camp.  All too often, all someone needs is to be pointed in the right direction, and I can't be arsed to fulfill the litany of requirements this community has for posting a good answer if that's all the OP needs.  Unfortunately, comments have very short shrift here.

Comment: This user is, erm, special.  [This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392514/what-can-i-do-about-a-user-consistently-spreading-misinformation) is about him.  Not much that can be done about that, but if the assistance looks unhelpful then the logical assumption is that it is and a "No longer needed" flag is the appropriate response.

Comment: @HansPassant: Interesting - I hadn't seen that meta question before, but after reading the question, I guessed at the user... and was right. Glad I'm not the only one to have noticed their "unusual" behavior and casual relationship with accuracy.

Comment: Why all the angst? Take their comment, turn it into an answer, give attribution.

Comment: If it would have worked I would have ;)

Comment: There is also the possibility of providing an answer in a comment for cases when it is not sure it is actually able to fully answer the question but the information could be useful in helping solve the problem.

Comment: @JoeW: Yeah, I'm okay with the occasions where someone comments something like "Hmm, have you tried xyz? It may be because...".  And if that works, I ask them to post as an answer.  However this was like "XYZ." (and it hasn't helped me solve the issue)

Answer (score -2):

If someone posts a comment with the answer, and despite the OP's invitation to post an official answer, they refuse to, there's not much more one can do. Or maybe there is…

- The OP themself could convert the comment into an answer, acknowledging the author and adding the appropriate link.
- The OP could encourage the commenter to provide further details in the comments and offer to fix any clumsy language errors and then politely ask the commenter to post their answer.
- The OP could actively encourage the author to post their answer as long as it works or has some validity, and promise to upvote the effort.

Comment: AFAIAC, if I offer the core of an answer in a comment and it's a 'correct' answer, the OP or anyone else can convert it into a formal answer. If the OP asks me to do so, I will — quite a number of my answers have a comment along the lines of 'converting comments into an answer' at the top.  Usually, there'll be some extra information in the answer compared to the comments.  If someone else provides an answer, preferably with some expansion on what's in my comment, that's fine with me — especially if they x-ref my comment (but that's not necessary if they knew the answer anyway).

Comment: I just went counting — about 70 (out of about 12,500) of my answers have some variant of 'converting comments into an answer' at the top.  That's less than 0.6% of my answers.  My search may have been too stringent to show them all (`user:15168 is:a convert comment answer`) because I've also used verbs such as 'transferring' too.

Comment: Mari-Lou A, you should add the usual flow of treating such answers: ask the commenter to post as an answer > wait a reasonable amount of time > post as *community wiki*. By refusing to post as an answer, the commenter gave up rights to it long ago (in fact, we give up these rights the moment we post anything under cc-by-sa license), but it is a common courtesy to post as a wiki, I had several of mine reposted (and even approved a couple of them explicitly) and reposted some myself.

Comment: @OlegValter if the "answer" in the comment is basically a link or consists of a single line, with no explanation, and no supporting evidence then anyone who converts the comment into a detailed and self-contained answer has worked harder than the commenter and deserves to be rewarded.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I am talking about a general, not an edge case here, I agree that if the comment is basically a link to a resource, it can be converted to an answer. If a comment or a set of comments address the issue of the OP and have a long-standing value, the effort of posters should be respected with a CV rather than attribution.