# Does SO allow blocking users who troll?

Tags: discussion

How can I block users who negate my question and have it closed?

Here's my only question I posted. Within minutes it's closed.

Does Stack Overflow allow blocking users who troll in the name of keeping things clean?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/76345950?noredirect=1

Any answer?

Comment: Please do take the [tour] and read [ask]. This question is completely off-topic.

Comment: _"Does stackoverflow allow blocking users who troll in the name of keeping things clean?"_ - What happened to your Q is not trolling. And SO actually _encourages_ quick closing of off-topic or sub-par questions. People are donating their free time on here to help others. So people that seek that help should respect the helpers by not wasting their time and making help them as easy as possible.

Comment: Could you explain why you posted that question on Stack Overflow? Like, what do you expect Stack Overflow to be for? Perhaps it may give some insights into what can be improved.

Comment: Your question is not suited for SO, unless you can compile a minimal reproduceable example where we can see the issue ourselves. SO is not a free debugging service for a site of your choice. Also note that your question looks more like a spam attempt than a real question: lot of links to job postings, no code, question ends with "I am facing a problem as below:" (but there is no "below").

Comment: Best way to deal with trolls: Write good questions/answers and flag comments/answers of the trolls. Do not start a discussion with a troll or complain about any downvote

Comment: I don't think you understand what the word 'troll' means.

Comment: Please take a look at the duplicate targets I added to understand more about how this site works. They explain more about what we expect from questions, and why your question was receiving downvotes.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, Stack Overflow moderators block/ban users who troll. You can bring this to our attention by raising a flag on the offending post or comment.

However, downvoting a question is not trolling. Everyone is invited to vote on posts—whether up or down—as they see fit, based on their assessment of the post's quality. Thus, a downvote represents little more than that voter's opinion about your post.

Also, that question does not appear to be on-topic for Stack Overflow. Which is why it was closed and, likely, why it was downvoted. **It looks like you're trying to report a bug with the Microsoft Careers site.** You cannot report those bugs here. You need to report those bugs to Microsoft.

If you actually work on the team who develops the Microsoft Careers site, and you're having this problem with your site, then please edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that other people can reproduce the problem and solve it for you.

Comment: _"Stack Overflow moderators block/ban users who troll. "_ - [I'm still waiting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392514/what-can-i-do-about-a-user-consistently-spreading-misinformation).

Comment: Throwback to the good old forum days where mods banned users for the lulz. Only for a minute or ten, because they could.

Comment: Like those times we banned [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)?